# What is a Non-Trivial Connected Graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

What is a "non-trivial connected graph"? What is a "non-trivial component"?
I am solving some graph theory problems and need clarification on the definitions of these terms.

Can anyone explain the terms with examples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trivial graph is the graph on one vertex. This graph meets the definition of connected vacuously (since an edge requires two vertices). A non-trivial connected graph is any connected graph that isn't this graph.

A non-trivial connected component is a connected component that isn't the trivial graph, which is another way of say that it isn't an isolated point.